# inserting an element in tensorshape as list, the whole lists become none

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to change a tensor's shape from (3,4) to (1,3,4), so I use get_shape().as_list() to get the original shape, and try to modify this list using insert, however, I find the original list containing the dimension information become None, what happened? Or what can I do if I want to reshape a tensor from (3,4) to (1,3,4)?

```
a=np.random.random([3,4])
a=tf.constant(a)
g=a.get_shape().as_list()
g
#[3,4]
g=a.get_shape().as_list().insert(0,1)
type(g)
#NoneType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use tf.reshape() ?

```
>>> a=np.random.random([3,4])
>>> a=tf.constant(a)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'Const_2:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float64>
>>> a=tf.reshape(a, (1, 3, 4))
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_2:0' shape=(1, 3, 4) dtype=float64>
```

Edit: In Python, .insert() method of lists does not return anything. Hence you get None type. Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm

You should use g as a temporary list. Try this;

```
>>> a=np.random.random([3,4])
>>> a=tf.constant(a)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float64>
>>> g=a.get_shape().as_list()
>>> g
[3, 4]
>>> g.insert(0, 1)
>>> g
[1, 3, 4]
>>> a=tf.reshape(a, g)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'Reshape:0' shape=(1, 3, 4) dtype=float64>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. what if I need to deal with much higher dimensional tensors, whose dimension is unknown to me. the example I gave is a little misleading.

Comment: @DDz if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And sorry for the delay....it takes some time to find the check mark...It's my first question here, and I didn't realize I need to check it. And I should read python tutorial more carefully to avoid such question....anyway, I think insert method return nothing is a really strange feature, as in my case, it can ruined the original list..